# Swiper-Slide-Active class when Swiper is multirow

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, swiper.js

I have Swiper set to show 2 rows per column, but when I do this then the Swiper-Slide-Active class are not properly set, i.e. this class is not applied to the slides (2) that are shown in the center of the swiper.

Any idea what am i doing wrong here?, settings for the swiper below:

```
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
                pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
                effect: 'coverflow',
                grabCursor: true,
                centeredSlides: true,
                slidesPerView: 'auto',
                slidesPerColumn: 2,
                spaceBetween: 20,
                simulateTouch: true,
                centeredSlides:true,
                slideToClickedSlide: true,
                paginationClickable:true,
                grabCursor:true,
                coverflow: {
                    rotate: 45,
                    stretch: 0,
                    depth: 100,
                    modifier: 1,
                    slideShadows: false
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, multirow Swiper is not compatible with **slidesPerView:'auto'**, so if it is possible for your layout, switch slidesPerView to some fixed value

Comment: after setting slidesPerView to a fixed value, the Swiper-Slide-Active class is still not applied to the right slide.

Comment: Maybe some example or JSfiddle with issue? That will be more helpful to realise where issue is